# A very simple thread pool using pthreads in C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, threadpool

I'm trying to understand some of the basics of using POSIX pthreads.  The kind of thing I need to do (eventually) is parallelize some computations, using a thread pool model.  At present I want to ensure I have a very basic sense for how the POSIX pthread model works.   So I'm trying to create the simplest thread pool that's general enough to do the kinds of things I want to do.  There will be some shared memory, an input queue, and an output queue, and there will be mutexes protecting each.  I've written some code that does just that but valgrind's helgrind tool does not like what I've done.  I suspect I'm missing something basic.   Do you have insights into my code?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

// the muticies, protectors of the shared resources
pthread_mutex_t coutLock;
pthread_mutex_t inQueueLock;
pthread_mutex_t outQueueLock;
// the shared data
std::list< std::string > inQueue;
std::list< std::string > outQueue;

struct thread_detail { // information to pass to worker threads
 unsigned long num;
};

extern "C" {
    void *workerThread(void *threadarg);
}

void *workerThread(void *threadarg) 
{
   struct thread_detail *my_data;
   my_data = (thread_detail *) threadarg;
   int taskid = my_data->num;
   std::stringstream ss; ss<<taskid; std::string taskString(ss.str());

   bool somethingTodo=true;
   while (somethingTodo) // keep on working until inQueue is empty 
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock( &inQueueLock );
      std::string workOnMe;
      if (inQueue.size()==0) { somethingTodo=false; }
      else
        {
         workOnMe = inQueue.front();
         inQueue.pop_front();
        }
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &inQueueLock );

      if (!somethingTodo) break;
      workOnMe = "thread " + taskString + " worked on " + workOnMe;
      // let's pretend this takes some time, add a delay to the computation
      struct timeval timeout;
      timeout.tv_sec = 0;  timeout.tv_usec = 100000; // 0.1 second delay 
      select( 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, & timeout );

      pthread_mutex_lock( &outQueueLock );
      outQueue.push_back( workOnMe );
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &outQueueLock );
    }

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned long comp_DONE=0; 
  unsigned long comp_START=0;
  // set-up the mutexes
  pthread_mutex_init( &coutLock, NULL );
  pthread_mutex_init( &inQueueLock, NULL );
  pthread_mutex_init( &outQueueLock, NULL );

  if (argc != 3) { std::cout<<"Program requires two arguments: (1) number of threads to use,"
                           " and (2) tasks to accomplish.\n"; exit(1); }
  unsigned long NUM_THREADS(atoi( argv[1] ));
  unsigned long comp_TODO(atoi(argv[2]));
  std::cout<<"Program will have "<<NUM_THREADS<<" threads, working on "<<comp_TODO<<" things \n";
  for (unsigned long i=0; i<comp_TODO; i++) // fill inQueue will rubbish data since this isn't an actual computation...
   {
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss<<"task "<<i; 
    inQueue.push_back(ss.str());
   }

  // start the worker threads
  std::list< pthread_t* > threadIdList; // just the thread ids
  std::list< thread_detail > thread_table; // for keeping track of information on the various threads we'll create
  for (unsigned long i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++) // start the threads
   {
    pthread_t *tId( new pthread_t );   threadIdList.push_back(tId);
    thread_detail Y; Y.num=i; thread_table.push_back(Y);
    int rc( pthread_create( tId, NULL, workerThread, (void *)(&(thread_table.back() )) ) );
    if (rc) { std::cout<<"ERROR; return code from pthread_create() "<<comp_START<<"\n"; std::cout.flush();
              exit(-1); }
   }
  // now we wait for the threads to terminate, perhaps updating the screen with info as we go. 
  std::string stringOut;
  while (comp_DONE != comp_TODO)
   {
         // poll the queue to get a status update on computation
         pthread_mutex_lock(&inQueueLock);
         comp_START = comp_TODO -  inQueue.size();
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&inQueueLock);
         pthread_mutex_lock(&outQueueLock);
         comp_DONE = outQueue.size();
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&outQueueLock);

         // update for users
         pthread_mutex_lock(&coutLock);
         for (unsigned long i=0; i<stringOut.length(); i++) std::cout<<"\b";
         std::stringstream ss; ss<<"started "<<comp_START<<" completed "<<comp_DONE<<" of "<<comp_TODO;  
         stringOut = ss.str();  std::cout<<stringOut;  std::cout.flush();
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&coutLock);

         // wait one second per update
         struct timeval timeout;
         timeout.tv_sec = 1;  timeout.tv_usec = 0;  
         select( 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, & timeout );
        } // big while loop

   // call join to kill all worker threads
   std::list< pthread_t* >::iterator i(threadIdList.begin());
  while (i!=threadIdList.end())
   {
    if (pthread_join( *(*i), NULL)!=0) { std::cout<<"Thread join error!\n"; exit(1); }
    delete (*i);
    threadIdList.erase(i++);  
   }
  std::cout<<"\n";

   // let the user know what happened
   for (std::list< std::string >::iterator i=outQueue.begin(); i!=outQueue.end(); i++)
    {
     std::cout<<(*i)<<"\n";
    }
    // clean-up
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&coutLock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&inQueueLock);  
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&outQueueLock);  
    // pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Here is the helgrind output when passing the arguments 2 40 to the compiled program.

```
valgrind -v --tool=helgrind ./thread1 2 40
==12394== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==12394== Copyright (C) 2007-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==12394== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12394== Command: ./thread1 2 40
==12394== 
--12394-- Valgrind options:
--12394--    --suppressions=/usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp
--12394--    -v
--12394--    --tool=helgrind
--12394-- Contents of /proc/version:
--12394--   Linux version 2.6.32-24-generic (buildd@yellow) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 5 09:20:59 UTC 2010
--12394-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, amd64-sse3-cx16
--12394-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--12394-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--12394-- Reading syms from /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1 (0x400000)
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/ld-2.11.1.so (0x4000000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/ld-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 99d13f6f wanted 0962e544)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/lib/ld-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/helgrind-amd64-linux (0x38000000)
--12394--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--12394-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp
--12394-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so (0x4a23000)
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so (0x4c25000)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x4018310 (index) redirected to 0x4c2be59 (index)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x4018390 (strcmp) redirected to 0x4c2bf4b (strcmp)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x40184a0 (strlen) redirected to 0x4c2bec5 (strlen)
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libregina-engine-4.6.1.so (0x4e31000)
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3.5.2 (0x52f7000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3.5.2 ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed d65050b9 wanted 1e40f6c0)
--12394--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so (0x5557000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 9da7e2f6 wanted 8161fac5)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/librt-2.11.1.so (0x5774000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/librt-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 0e4f4ece wanted 920c9bed)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/lib/librt-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3 (0x597c000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3 ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 86f1fa27 wanted 5f1ca823)
--12394--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 (0x5b93000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 7b5bd5a5 wanted e2f63673)
--12394--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/libm-2.11.1.so (0x5ea7000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/libm-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 043548c3 wanted a081b93d)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/lib/libm-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x612a000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 7c01dfc9 wanted 9d78e511)
--12394--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/libc-2.11.1.so (0x6341000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/libc-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed c73d5a83 wanted 02758e3e)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/lib/libc-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6 (0x66c4000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6 ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed c2590bed wanted 7aaa27a0)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.6 ..
--12394-- Reading syms from /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so (0x6a14000)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- .. CRC mismatch (computed 4a29f474 wanted e0b8d72c)
--12394-- Reading debug info from /usr/lib/debug/lib/libdl-2.11.1.so ..
--12394-- REDIR: 0x55603c0 (pthread_mutex_lock) redirected to 0x4c299fb (pthread_mutex_lock)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x5561a00 (pthread_mutex_unlock) redirected to 0x4c29e8c (pthread_mutex_unlock)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x63bd520 (malloc) redirected to 0x4c28a06 (malloc)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x63bf360 (calloc) redirected to 0x4c27cc9 (calloc)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x5c5e380 (operator new[](unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c28e97 (operator new[](unsigned long))
--12394-- REDIR: 0x5c5e250 (operator new(unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2921f (operator new(unsigned long))
--12394-- REDIR: 0x5c5c380 (operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x4c28328 (operator delete(void*))
--12394-- REDIR: 0x5c5c3c0 (operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4c27fa4 (operator delete[](void*))
--12394-- REDIR: 0x63c3fe0 (strlen) redirected to 0x4a235dc (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x63c4010 (__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4c2be91 (strlen)
--12394-- REDIR: 0x63c7c60 (memcpy) redirected to 0x4c2bfdb (memcpy)
Program will have 2 threads, working on 40 things 
--12394-- REDIR: 0x555dd60 (pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4c2d4c7 (pthread_create@*)
==12394== Thread #2 was created
==12394==    at 0x64276BE: clone (clone.S:77)
==12394==    by 0x555E172: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (createthread.c:75)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D42C: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:230)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D4CF: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:257)
==12394==    by 0x401C22: main (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394== 
==12394== Thread #1 is the program's root thread
==12394== 
==12394== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x7fefffcf0 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x4C2D54C: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:200)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #1
==12394==    at 0x4C2D440: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:235)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D4CF: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:257)
==12394==    by 0x401C22: main (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394== 
started 21 completed 19 of 40==12394== Thread #3 was created
==12394==    at 0x64276BE: clone (clone.S:77)
==12394==    by 0x555E172: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (createthread.c:75)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D42C: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:230)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D4CF: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:257)
==12394==    by 0x401C22: main (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394== 
==12394== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x63401a7 by thread #3
==12394==    at 0x613A4D7: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A947: _Unwind_Resume (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x4019C9: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394==    by 0x555D9C9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==12394==    by 0x64276FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x6138331: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x5563F42: pthread_once (pthread_once.S:104)
==12394==    by 0x613A4C9: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A7B6: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x556508F: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:130)
==12394==    by 0x555EEB4: pthread_exit (pthreadP.h:265)
==12394==    by 0x40198E: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394== 
==12394== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x63401a6 by thread #3
==12394==    at 0x6139A12: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x6139AA8: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A724: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A982: _Unwind_Resume (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x4019C9: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394==    by 0x555D9C9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==12394==    by 0x64276FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x613832A: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x5563F42: pthread_once (pthread_once.S:104)
==12394==    by 0x613A4C9: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A7B6: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x556508F: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:130)
==12394==    by 0x555EEB4: pthread_exit (pthreadP.h:265)
==12394==    by 0x40198E: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394== 
==12394== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x63401b0 by thread #3
==12394==    at 0x6139AD7: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A724: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A982: _Unwind_Resume (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x4019C9: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394==    by 0x555D9C9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==12394==    by 0x64276FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x6138370: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x5563F42: pthread_once (pthread_once.S:104)
==12394==    by 0x613A4C9: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A7B6: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x556508F: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:130)
==12394==    by 0x555EEB4: pthread_exit (pthreadP.h:265)
==12394==    by 0x40198E: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394== 
--12394-- REDIR: 0x63bede0 (free) redirected to 0x4c28616 (free)
started 40 completed 40 of 40--12394-- REDIR: 0x555ef30 (pthread_join) redirected to 0x4c29796 (pthread_join)

thread 0 worked on task 0
thread 1 worked on task 1
thread 0 worked on task 2
thread 1 worked on task 3
thread 0 worked on task 4
thread 1 worked on task 5
thread 0 worked on task 6
thread 1 worked on task 7
thread 0 worked on task 8
thread 1 worked on task 9
thread 0 worked on task 10
thread 1 worked on task 11
thread 0 worked on task 12
thread 1 worked on task 13
thread 0 worked on task 14
thread 1 worked on task 15
thread 0 worked on task 16
thread 1 worked on task 17
thread 0 worked on task 18
thread 1 worked on task 19
thread 0 worked on task 20
thread 1 worked on task 21
thread 0 worked on task 22
thread 1 worked on task 23
thread 0 worked on task 24
thread 1 worked on task 25
thread 0 worked on task 26
thread 1 worked on task 27
thread 0 worked on task 28
thread 1 worked on task 29
thread 0 worked on task 30
thread 1 worked on task 31
thread 0 worked on task 32
thread 1 worked on task 33
thread 0 worked on task 34
thread 1 worked on task 35
thread 0 worked on task 36
thread 1 worked on task 37
thread 0 worked on task 38
thread 1 worked on task 39
==12394== 
==12394== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 804 from 64)
==12394== 
==12394== 1 errors in context 1 of 4:
==12394== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x63401a7 by thread #3
==12394==    at 0x613A4D7: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A947: _Unwind_Resume (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x4019C9: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394==    by 0x555D9C9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==12394==    by 0x64276FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x6138331: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x5563F42: pthread_once (pthread_once.S:104)
==12394==    by 0x613A4C9: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A7B6: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x556508F: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:130)
==12394==    by 0x555EEB4: pthread_exit (pthreadP.h:265)
==12394==    by 0x40198E: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394== 
==12394== 
==12394== 2 errors in context 2 of 4:
==12394== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x63401b0 by thread #3
==12394==    at 0x6139AD7: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A724: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A982: _Unwind_Resume (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x4019C9: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394==    by 0x555D9C9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==12394==    by 0x64276FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x6138370: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x5563F42: pthread_once (pthread_once.S:104)
==12394==    by 0x613A4C9: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A7B6: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x556508F: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:130)
==12394==    by 0x555EEB4: pthread_exit (pthreadP.h:265)
==12394==    by 0x40198E: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394== 
==12394== 
==12394== 2 errors in context 3 of 4:
==12394== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x63401a6 by thread #3
==12394==    at 0x6139A12: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x6139AA8: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A724: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A982: _Unwind_Resume (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x4019C9: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394==    by 0x555D9C9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:300)
==12394==    by 0x64276FC: clone (clone.S:112)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x613832A: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x5563F42: pthread_once (pthread_once.S:104)
==12394==    by 0x613A4C9: ??? (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x613A7B6: _Unwind_ForcedUnwind (in /lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
==12394==    by 0x556508F: __pthread_unwind (unwind.c:130)
==12394==    by 0x555EEB4: pthread_exit (pthreadP.h:265)
==12394==    by 0x40198E: workerThread(void*) (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D558: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:202)
==12394== 
==12394== 
==12394== 2 errors in context 4 of 4:
==12394== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x7fefffcf0 by thread #2
==12394==    at 0x4C2D54C: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:200)
==12394==  This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #1
==12394==    at 0x4C2D440: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:235)
==12394==    by 0x4C2D4CF: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:257)
==12394==    by 0x401C22: main (in /home/rybu/prog/regina/exercise/thread1)
==12394== 
--12394-- 
--12394-- used_suppression:    610 helgrind-glibc2X-101
--12394-- used_suppression:    192 helgrind---...-*Unwind*-*pthread_unwind*
--12394-- used_suppression:      2 helgrind-glibc2X-112
==12394== 
==12394== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 804 from 64)
```

I'm not so confident when it comes to interpreting helgrind output.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: +1 for giving us not only code but also the description of the error messages.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Maybe false positives from helgrind?

Comment: Okay, after playing enough with enough code written by other people that uses pthreads successfully, it appears that the trouble is helgrind simply giving out way too many false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several of your errors come from `libgcc_s.so`. Some of them appear to occur during thread initialization, before your function is even called.

Try compiling with `gcc -pthread` to make sure the compiler knows what's going on.

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  Don't you get the same problems if you run helgrind on the executable?

Comment: I've notice the application "pbzip2" uses a thread pool, it's also written in a C/C++ style like my code. Helgrind has only one complaint when pbzip2 is running, it's same as the topmost complaint in my helgrind output.  So that complaint is perhaps not so important, but the others I don't know what they mean.

Comment: @Ryan: The other errors mention `pthread_once`, which is used to initialize static variables. Also, we know they occur before the loop in the workers. Since the only interesting thing there is creation of a `stringstream` and a few `string`s, try building a dummy `stringstream` and doing something similar in `main` before `pthread_create`, just to initialize the related globals. Also, it might be worthwhile to try different versions of the compiler.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.3.3 (under Ubuntu 10.04) at home. I also have gcc 4.2.4 installed at home. Both have the same problem. On the office computer I have 4.4.3 and 4.3.4 installed, both with the same problem.  Also running Ubuntu 10.04 at the office.  I eliminated the stringstream initializations and calls before thread initialization, with no change in the valgrind output.  I'll try similar tweaks to the other things that appear before initialization of the threads.

Comment: I'll see if I can try it on some non-Ubuntu (or at least non 10.04) systems soon.  Most of the other systems I have access to don't have valgrind installed.

Comment: Your comments have been the most helpful, and helped me identify the source of the problem -- valgrind's general over-exuberance. I'd give points to Starkey, too, if I could.

Answer (score 7):

You are using a busy loop:

```
  if (inQueue.size()==0) { somethingTodo=false; }
  else
    {
     workOnMe = inQueue.front();
     inQueue.pop_front();
    }
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &inQueueLock );

  if (!somethingTodo) continue;
```

look up condition variable.
That way your thread is not consuming resources waiting for work to appear in the queue.
[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552677/why-this-thread-safe-queue-creates-a-deadlock)

You tagged the question C++ but you are using C style casts.
Also note that in C++ you do not need to add struct here.

```
my_data = (struct thread_detail *) threadarg;
```

Technically you should declare your callback function to use the C ABI (as this is a C library.

```
extern "C" void *workerThread(void *threadarg);
```

Personal choice move the * beside the type (but that is just my personal pref).

You are not using RAII. So your lock/unlock senarios are not exception safe.

```
  pthread_mutex_lock( &inQueueLock );

  // Stuff that could throw.

  pthread_mutex_unlock( &inQueueLock );
```

Even if stuff in the middle can not throw now. You are assuming that somebody will not add code that that does not throw in the future. Make it safe by creating a lock object.

Comment: The user named "Dima" tagged the question as C++, not me.  Regarding the "busy loop" comment, the worker thread is only called if the queue is non-empty, and once its empty the worker thread terminates.   So it's never wasting resources on an empty queue. I think maybe you're thinking my code is more sophisticated than it is.  The worker thread pool only starts when there's a job to do, and then it gets killed.  This does not seem to address the helgrind output.  Judging from people's feedback so far is sounds like helgrind does not give reliable information, even on "good" pthread code?

Comment: Regarding your latter comment on the mutex lock/unlock calls -- for now I just want to ensure this stand-alone experiment runs properly.  This is not code that somebody else is going to touch. I'm an amateur programmer.  I'm okay not complying with RAII.  This is just about me understanding pthreads for now.

Comment: @Ryan: It would be clearer to say `if ( ! somethingToDo ) break;` rather than `continue`, since the `continue` leads immediately to a loop exit.

Comment: @ Ryan Budney: If you writting primerly in C then I withdraw all the comments and consider it good for a C program (though slightly untidy). But I would highlite the point the Potatoswatter made about the use of continue.

Comment: I replaced continue with break. I'm still confused as to why helgrind doesn't like this program.  Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm missing an extern "C" {} block for your thread function at least, since a C library would expect a C ABI. Other than that, I can't see anything obvious.

E.g. create a prototype like:

```
extern "C" {
    void *workerThread(void *threadarg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That actually depends on your compiler. In both gnu and clang you dont need the extern c around the function call. Though I have heard in some compilers you do.