# debug multi-threaded programs tips

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, debugging, gdb

I wonder how to debug `multi-threaded programs` effectively.

#### What I've done so far:

> 1. I read some `gdb` reference, but all of them talk little about `multi-thread` debuging.
> 2. I used `gdb` to debug my c++ programs.
> 3. [linux thread reference](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Abstract)

### What's your tricks to share?

### Skills

> 1. `1>` Understand the code structure well. `2>` Debug thread by thread. `3>` In terms of exact time-stamps implemented.

**PS:** The approch still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTmAknUbpB0&feature=share&list=PLckFgM6dUP2hc4iy-IdKFtqR9TeZWMPjm&index=11) may be of help to you.

Comment: @Borgleader Can't open the url.. Thank u on the same.

Comment: Avoid the problem completely by doing it right in the first place. I haven't had a multi-threading bug in decades.

Comment: @EJP I debug the program to see what in hand is going on step by step.  I want to make a clear picture of the thread modle.

Comment: @luoluo I only debug programs that have bugs in them. If you don't understand your own code, write code that you do understand.

Comment: I understand it, but something going wrong. Then step by step maybe is a good way to figure out what's goign wrong.

Comment: Do you expect timestamps to provide absolute truths? Hint: things may become visible to different CPUs at different times.

Comment: @ninjalj We don't need the same truth. But on certain cpu, we can solve the problem. which is the main point to me.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981011/c-programming-debugging-with-pthreads

Comment: @Brendan helps a lot. thx.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable watchdog
2. Assign each thread a unique id/name. This way you may get thread id inside any function and know for sure what thread executes it.
3. Learn how to use Threads Window in Visual Studio:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx

Comment: -1: This won't work on Linux.

Comment: Thread names work on Linux (pthread_setname_np).

Comment: how do you disable watchdog in linux???

Answer (score 0):

Using the debugger to understand a program might work well for single threaded systems.

It definitly doesn't work (well) for problems involving more then one thread. This is per design, as human nature is single threaded.

So to get into a multithreaded system:

1. Identify all threads and how they depend on another by reading and understanding the sources.
2. Debug each thread on its own. This might imply disabling or synchronising other threads.
3. Add detailed logging in terms of exact time-stamps implemented to **not add synchronisation** to the threads

This approach follows the paradigm of doing one thing at a time.

Comment: Given I wrote the source myself, I understood the source well. From time to time, some problem occur, I had to dubug it. So what the works  I can do to figure out what's going on. Any way, thx.

Comment: @luoluo: See point 2., 2nd sentence.

Comment: It's a good layout, anything in detail?

Comment: @luoluo: I added a 3rd point.

Comment: how can I achieve 3rd point?